# Trying to display a binary image through HttpHandler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to display a binary image through an httphandler. Here is the code I have:

**ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "AnswerPostHandler.ashx",
    data: "imgid=1380",
    success: function (msg) {
           $(parent).append(msg);
    },
    error: function (msg){
           alert(msg);
    }
});
```

**Handler code**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
    try
    {
        krystaladbDataContext db = new krystaladbDataContext();

        var binimg = (from i in db.image_tables
                      where i.IMG_ID.Equals(1380)
                      select i.IMG_THUMB).Single();


        byte[] b = binimg.ToArray();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

something still seems not right here and it is dumping binary data. Base64 encoding is also a choice here but I have tested it , and it doesn't work on IE 7 ( literally chops part of the image ).

can you advice me on what i am doing wrong here and how I can make it right? thanks

Comment: No need to construct Image. Just write byte array - context.Response.BinaryWrite(b);

Comment: i tried to do that, but the image won't display ...

Comment: To can't write the ajax output (binary) to the dom element. You may either use base64 DataURI (in that case you have to modify handler code) but it has many issues with browsers. The best and simple option is that use - image tag.  <img src="your_handler.ashx?id=122"/>

Comment: thanks @AVD , but in that case what is returned from the handler ?

Comment: You are writing bytes to the Response stream. The code seems OK to me.  (You may write byte array instead of generate Image). Have a look at my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handler code,

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
    try
    {
        krystaladbDataContext db = new krystaladbDataContext();
        var binimg = (from i in db.image_tables
                      where i.IMG_ID.Equals(1380)
                      select i.IMG_THUMB).Single();


        byte[] b = binimg.ToArray();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(b);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

and html `<img>` markup,

```
<img src="AnswerPostHandler.ashx?imgid=1380" alt="None" id="img1" />
```

Or you may request via jQuery code:

```
 $("#showImageButton").click(function () {
                $("#img1").attr("src", "AnswerPostHandler.ashx?imgid=1380");
            });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this @AVD . I spend hours searching for this.

Comment: Any Idea how to directly download a file this way?

Comment: Use `<a href='AnswerPostHandler.ashx?imgid=1380'>Right click + save as</a>`

Answer (score -1):

it will be easier to do something like
$(parent).html('')

binary stream will be hard to implement in browser as a img source.